# Cannot read property 'displayAvatarURL' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to run an async module in Djs V.12 but i got error says `Cannot read property 'displayAvatarURL' of undefined`.

Here's my code:

```
const {
  MessageEmbed,
} = require("discord.js");
const {
  NAME,
  BUILD
} = require("./../../config.json");

module.exports = {
  name: 'musiclist',
  aliases: ['mlist'],
  category: 'fun',
  description: 'musiclist',
  usage: 'musiclist',
  run: async (message, client) => {
    let music_list = ["p (play dari yt link)", "dc (kalo pke command ini tag gw)", "q (cek queue)"];
    let list = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Music Command List")
      .setColor(0xffed2a)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setDescription(music_list)
      .setFooter(`${NAME} | ${BUILD}`, client.user.displayAvatarURL());
    await message.channel.send(list);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if the code is wrong, is this a **bug** or something?

**EDIT**
Here's my main file

```
if (!body.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
  let args = body.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  if (cmd.length === 0) return;
  let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
  if (!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));
  if (command) {
    try {
      command.run(client, message, args, Menu);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err).then(() => {
        message,reply("BOT error");
      });
    }
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not you can use `client`, I'd suggest using `message.author.avatarURL()`. So instead of using `client`, just reference the `message` object you have.

Comment: I tried replace `client.user.displayAvatarURL()` with `message.author.avatarURL()` but the error still same. `avatarURL() is undefined`

Comment: I'm confused why you put `const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");` instead of the usual `const Discord = require('discord.js');` configuration, is it mostly because it's a separated command that you have the main file everything in a different place?

Comment: I have made the files separately, so just need to write like that. At first I thought that `run: async (message, client)` is connected with the main files

Comment: If you wrote `console.log(message);` right after you declare the `async function` what will you receive? You'll have to scroll a little bit up before you get the error message of course. I just want to check if the `message` object has been passed properly.

Comment: @RezkyRizaldi can you update a simple code which shows how the `run` is used?

Comment: As @HoangDao mentioned, we need to see how you use `run`. Make sure you pass the variables in the correct order: `.run(message, client)`

Comment: Oh, it's fixed! I change the order from `run: async (messge, client)` to `run: async (client, message)`. But I don't know why it happened